# How to make a gradle project depend on another gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I am developing two gradle projects, project A and project B. Project A is dependent on project B. I want to add project B into the dependencies of project A, like adding a dependency from maven central.

I could compile project B into a fat jar and add the jar file into the dependencies of project A, but there is a problem: the dependencies of project A and project B conflicted.

For example, there is `compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'` in both projects.

Comment: See [Authoring Multi-Project Builds](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I could compile project B into a fat jar and add the jar file into the dependencies of project A

No, never do that, of course it will trigger dependencies issues. `ProjectA` has no way to determine if a dependency is a duplicate in a fat jar. `Gradle` has a [built-in way](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sec:declaring_project_dependency) to handle it.

```
project(':projectA') {
    dependencies {
        compile project(':projectB')
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want to add project A into a git repository, where should I put project B?

Comment: why not also in git ?

Comment: Can I specify the version of project B?